# How can I say ‘When I clik again‘ on Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trie to make a app like this (I use label to label LOL)

```
                [label setText: @"Hello"];
                If (press the button again) {
                   [label setText: @"World"];
   }
```

How can I say this expression :

```
              If (press the button again)
```

Comment: Use state machine to track how many clicks have happened.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a counter like:

```
@property int counter;
```

and every time a user clicks the button just increment the counter:

```
_counter ++;
```

then check:

```
if (_counter > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First drag a `UILabel` and `UIButton` to the ViewControllers view in Storyboard.

Connect the `UILabel` to `IBOutlet` by CNTRL+click and dragging it to your code (I anmed mine helloWorldLabel).

Then CNTRL+click and drag from your `UIButton` to your code to make an `IBAction` method (mine called buttonPressedMethod).

And finally put this code in you method body:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressedMethod:(id)sender {
    if ([self.helloWorldLabel.text isEqual:@"Hello"]) {
        self.helloWorldLabel.text = @"World";
    }
    else
    {
        self.helloWorldLabel.text = @"Hello";
    }
}
```

Your total picture should look like this:

[image: total pic]

Now you can click all you want and the label will change accordingly to Hello or World!